# remove children from object for JSON serialisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, projection, javascriptserializer

I have an object with children that I'm using JavaScriptSerializer to convert to JSON. I'm using MVC and using the JavaScriptSerializer in a view as so:

```
@Html.Raw(serializer.Serialize(Model.Designs)
```

My "designs" object has the children "DesignDeliveries" but I need to remove these from the JSON string so I've tried using projection but cannot get the format I require

So my Designs object is as follows:

```
[{
"BookingDesignId": "e90e9500-0a6a-4d1b-a82a-fa7ca2d7c034",
"DesignName": "Design 600",
"Quantity": 100,
"DesignDeliveries": [{
    "BookingId": "3706a896-3b8f-454f-acc8-6540441a3e4a",
    "Quantity": 50,
    "BookingDesignId": "e90e9500-0a6a-4d1b-a82a-fa7ca2d7c034",
    "DepotId": "9"
},
{
    "BookingId": "3706a896-3b8f-454f-acc8-6540441a3e4a",
    "Quantity": 50,
    "BookingDesignId": "e90e9500-0a6a-4d1b-a82a-fa7ca2d7c034",
    "DepotId": "18"
}]
}];
```

However, I need:

```
[{
"BookingDesignId": "e90e9500-0a6a-4d1b-a82a-fa7ca2d7c034",
"DesignName": "Design 600",
"Quantity": 100,
"DesignDeliveries": [];
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it have to be empty, or can you just not serialize it at all?

Comment: Hi Nathan...thanks for replying..it needs to be empty. I'm using it to create a knockout js viewmodel. Madman's answer below works. I had tried using Clear() but when projecting to an anonymous type which didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone **Model.Designs**, clear your collection of **DesignDeliveries**, serialize cloned Designs again.

Comment: Thanks Madman...that works a treat...just gotta figure out best way to clone now!.

Comment: Here is good solution for cloning objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically